# Access admin for sub directory website

Tags: admin, development

I have a website at http://www.avantalarm.com/ and I've created a development site at http://www.avantalarm.com/dev/ and everything seems to be working fine, however when I go to http://www.avantalarm.com/dev/admin to reach the development admin page, it redirects me to the main admin page for my main site.  I don't know a ton about .htaccess and I'm not sure if that's the problem, but I'd love to be able to reach my dev site's admin page.  Any help would be appreciated.  If I can offer up any code let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access you admin on the dev website. https://www.avantalarm.com/dev/index.php/admin
I don't know what can cause this. Maybe it's a custom extension. I saw that you are using `BalkeTechnologies_StoreMaintenance` that has a custom router. Could  be that.
Anyway you now can acccess the admin on the dev website.
**[Edit]**
Also the base url should be changed in `core_config_data`.

Comment: I did get to that part of the site but when logging in it again redirects me to the root admin page, and doesn't log me in.  It does seem that I can get to the dev admin by using https:// instead of http:// but it still redirects me to the root site.

Comment: I assume you cloned the files and the database. Did you change the base url for the dev site in the table `core_config_data`. I have a hunch that you didn't. If you did, clear the cache also.

Comment: That was it.  Should I accept answer even though the answer was in the comment?  I'm new to Stack Exchange rules.

Comment: I did this and I'm still redirected to the parent site :(